# Remove all occurrences of a value in a list in Erlang?

Tags: list, erlang, filtering, list-comprehension

I have a list of values that looks something like this:

```
["Some", "random", "values", [], "in", "a", [], "list"].
```

I would like to create a new list with the empty list items removed. Like this:

```
["Some", "random", "values", "in", "a", "list"].
```

What is the easiest way of going about this? I assume using list comprehensions to build a new list is going to be the most efficient way of doing this. How would I filter this list using list comprehensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List comprehensions are a neater lists:filter/2:

```
[E || E <- List, E /= []]
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using `lists:filter`.

```
List = ["Some", "random", "values", [], "in", "a", [], "list"],
lists:filter(fun(X) -> X /= [] end, List).
```

`lists:filter` takes a fun and a list. The fun should take a list item and return true or false. If the fun returns `true` the item is returned in the new list.

More information can be found here: http://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=Filtering_Lists